# Fluent validator with minimal api endpoint never gets executed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, minimal-apis

I'm trying to implement f[luent validation extension](https://github.com/benfoster/o9d-aspnet) on minimal api endpoint project

but I cannot manage to make it work

the project is .net 7 version with

```
  <PackageReference Include="O9d.AspNet.FluentValidation" Version="0.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" />
```

Following documentation I try with following

```
var test = app.MapGroup("/")
    .WithValidationFilter();
test.MapPost("/test-model", ([Validate][FromBody] TestModel model ) => "Hello World!");

app.Run();

public class TestModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
    {
        public TestModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).GreaterThan(0);
        }
    }
}
```

whatever I put in the body request it never get executed in the validator.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are missing one step - you need to register validators. For example using the ability to register all from assembly (see [FluentValidation integration with ASP.NET Core docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html)):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();

var app = builder.Build();
 
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the Author's [blog](https://benfoster.io/blog/minimal-api-validation-endpoint-filters/), Make sure to add this to your `Program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

I think this was mistakenly missed out in the `README.md` of this package.